# LINQ syntax command in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, linq

Here is my code in c#. I need to convert to vb.net. I already use some of online converter but seems not correct.

```
        var listResult = new List<GridViewO365Model>();
        listResult.Add(new GridViewO365Model("AB", 1, DateTime.Now, "ROC1", "CO1", "CODesc1", "ReType1", "Error 1"));
        listResult.Add(new GridViewO365Model("FF", 1, DateTime.Now.AddHours(1), "ROC1", "CO1", "CODesc1", "ReType1", "Error 1"));
        listResult.Add(new GridViewO365Model("GG", 1, DateTime.Now.AddHours(2), "ROC1", "CO1", "CODesc1", "ReType1", "Error 1"));
        listResult.Add(new GridViewO365Model("CD", 2, DateTime.Now, "ROC2", "CO2", "CODesc2", "ReType2", "Error 2"));

        listResult = (from p in listResult
                     group p by p.ReqID into grp
                     select grp.OrderByDescending(g => g.LogDate).First()).ToList();
```

I just need the LINQ command in VB. Help anybody?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another take on this:

- The [initializer syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293617.aspx) shorthand is also available to VB, which I've applied to your collection creation
- Since the C# query mixes both query and lambda syntax, I've standardised on lambda syntax in VB

```
Dim listResult As New List(Of GridViewO365Model) From {
     New GridViewO365Model("AB", 1, DateTime.Now, "ROC1", "CO1", "CODesc1", "ReType1", "Error 1"),
     New GridViewO365Model("AB", 1, DateTime.Now, "ROC1", "CO1", "CODesc1", "ReType1", "Error 1"),
     New GridViewO365Model("FF", 1, DateTime.Now.AddHours(1), "ROC1", "CO1", "CODesc1", "ReType1", "Error 1"),
     New GridViewO365Model("GG", 1, DateTime.Now.AddHours(2), "ROC1", "CO1", "CODesc1", "ReType1", "Error 1"),
     New GridViewO365Model("CD", 2, DateTime.Now, "ROC2", "CO2", "CODesc2", "ReType2", "Error 2")}

listResult = listResult _
   .GroupBy(Function(p) p.ReqId) _
   .Select(Function(grp) grp.OrderByDescending(Function(g) g.LogDate).First) _
   .ToList()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim listResult = New List(Of GridViewO365Model)()
listResult.Add(New GridViewO365Model("AB", 1, DateTime.Now, "ROC1", "CO1", "CODesc1", _
    "ReType1", "Error 1"))
listResult.Add(New GridViewO365Model("FF", 1, DateTime.Now.AddHours(1), "ROC1", "CO1", "CODesc1", _
    "ReType1", "Error 1"))
listResult.Add(New GridViewO365Model("GG", 1, DateTime.Now.AddHours(2), "ROC1", "CO1", "CODesc1", _
    "ReType1", "Error 1"))
listResult.Add(New GridViewO365Model("CD", 2, DateTime.Now, "ROC2", "CO2", "CODesc2", _
    "ReType2", "Error 2"))

listResult = (From grp In From p In listResultGroup p By p.ReqIDgrp.OrderByDescending(Function(g) g.LogDate).First()).ToList()
```

There are  number of online C# to VB converters online. You can use that with little modification.